# Timing a MySql Colum c# & php

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql

I need to submit a query to a database of course but some of the data needs to count down so this is essentially what is needed.

1. User clicks c# application button
2. Data submitted to the db
3. The "status" turns to a 1
4. The "time" row counts down for a time the user submits
5. Once the time counts all the way to 0 the "status" goes to 0

I know how to submit the data but the changing of the time and status is confusing me, also I have to assume they might close the application after submit.

Comment: Are you trying to set some kind of time limit?

Comment: Not a time limit, the user will input a time to do an action for, I wanna count-down that action in the db and not allow them to redo said action until the time runs out and status = 0 again. The first form is a login if that matters.

Comment: Look into using a cron job / task scheduler. Run a script that will check for action times that have expired or are due to be expired.

Comment: You just cannot countdown in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong approach.

You should store the time of the click in the database. The next time the user clicks, you compare that time with now() to allow or not the action.